# How to boot OpenWRT on VMware Fusion from .img file?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, openwrt, bootable, disk-image

I have VMware Fusion 10.

I have created VM with `Other Linux 3.x kernel`.

I have downloaded OpenWRT OS image `openwrt-18.06.1-x86-64-combined-ext4.img`

**My question is** how can I boot my OpenWRT OS from that `.img` file on my VM?

1. When I start my VM I have this screen:

[image]

2. Then VM opens Boot Manager:

[image]

So, how to tell VM to boot OS from `.img` file?

I'm on macOS High Sierra 10.13.4

Comment: Welcome, You should convert the `.img` to `.vmdk`. I am not experienced with Vmware but it work perfectly under VirtualBox.

Comment: See this answer on SO : https://stackoverflow.com/a/454914/5848185

Comment: OpenWrt requires legacy boot, I think. I'm pretty sure it won't boot with EFI.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, What legacy boot?

Comment: You'll have to find the right setting in VMware Fusion to boot the guest with legacy boot instead of EFI.